# RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument when tunnel routing

Tags: routes, tun

I set up a routing of TUN at my server like below:

```
10.0.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.1.2 
192.168.1.0/24 dev tun0  scope link 
default via 10.0.1.1 dev eth0
```

If I use "ip route get" to check the routing from eth0, there is no problem as below:

> ip r g 192.168.1.3 from 10.0.1.3 iif eth0

```
192.168.1.3 from 10.0.1.3 dev tun0  src 10.0.1.2 

    cache  mtu 1462 advmss 1422 hoplimit 64 iif eth0
```

But if I used as below:

> ip r g 192.168.1.3 from 10.0.1.3 iif tun0

```
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

Supposedly it should still work. I think some network config issue is here. Any thoughts? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem was fixed. rp_filter need to be set "0" to allow the traffic to be routed out to the same device.

Comment: Or "2" loose mode is enough to most of cases.